# upgrade texlive from 2017 to 2020 in ubuntu 18/04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, texlive

I am using the following version of texlive

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.34; using libpng 1.6.34
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with poppler version 0.62.0
```

Someone suggested me to install some package. They asked me to "install with TeX Live Package manager". I then checked I am using an older version of texlive (2017 version).

How can I upgrade to texlive 2020 version?

Comment: "Someone suggested me to install some package." - not informative at all. Are you sure that you really need TexLive-2020? What is particular reason for this? Which tex package do you miss in say 2018 or 2019?

Comment: the reason to move to 2020 is that it is a new version. Not that something important to me is missing in 2018 or 2019. @N0rbert a user suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585412/font-is-automatically-coming-in-italics-for-definitions-and-remarks/585437?noredirect=1#comment1471681_585437

Comment: In my 18.04 LTS with default 2017 texlive your document is [normally rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWfMa.png) using Gummi (by both pdftex and latexmk). You are doing something wrong or have local packages in home folder or elsewhere.

Comment: @N0rbert the other user said the same thing. I do not know what is the problem or how to fix it

Comment: You can try to list locally installed tex-packages by `ls -al $HOME/texmf; tlmgr repository list; tlmgr info --only-installed` command.

Comment: @N0rbert It says the following : "ls: cannot access '/home/--/texmf': No such file or directory
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
Cannot determine type of tlpdb from /home/--/texmf!
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/--/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 6424.
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
Cannot determine type of tlpdb from /home/--/texmf!
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/--/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 6424.
"